# Convert geometry to lat and long

Tags: sql-server

I found in my database that shops location represented as `geometry` datatype.

Is it possible to convert to `lat` and `long` coordinates and use it as input for bing maps?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

This works for geometry types in sql server

```
SELECT  [Geometry].STX AS [Longitude],
    [Geometry].STY AS [Latitude]
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: STX is Longitude not lat.

Answer (score 3):

The magic 8-ball says "all signs point to 'yes'". [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933968.aspx) shows Lat and Long methods. So, you'd do:

```
select 
   Geometry.Lat as [Latitude],
   Geometry.Long as [Longitude]
from dbo.your_table
```

By the way, if it's in your power to change the name of that column, do so; you wouldn't call a column with data type integer "int".

Comment: He said geometry datatype not geography.

Comment: Then there is no way short of divination. That is, there's nothing inherent to the geometry data type that says where it's located on the planet Earth. Which is a *really* compelling reason to use the geography datatype for geographic data.

Comment: these properties are for geography, not geometry

Comment: @AnasAL-zghoul - yes. But also, use the right data type. If your data represents geographic data (for which latitude and longitude are meaningful concepts), use the geography data type. If you've decided to use the geometry to represent that data, extract out the properties that were put in. That is, a choice was made to store latitude as either the x or y coordinate and longitude in the other. Talk with whomever created the data, ask what that choice was, and extract as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The post is a bit old, but...

You need to use some resource that can do projections. Many shops have access to ESRI REST Geometry services and a common exposed service is `Project`.

Here are the manual steps, you can repackage them into a script/procedure using your normal DB tools:

--QA data from a known point with geom named ShapeGeom

```
select top 1 ShapeGeom.ToString(),Lat,Long from My_ADDRESS_POINTS
```

returns: POINT (5786835.7214864492 2235317.366254434)    35.10721420   -120.59089280

--extract/reformat x,y from POINT:  5786835.7214864492,2235317.366254434

--REST call - your path will be different

```
--Use inSR with the SRID of your Geometry data
select top 1  ShapeGeom.STSrid from  My_ADDRESS_POINTS
```

--http????/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?**inSR=2229**&outSR=4251&geometries=**5786835.7214864492%2C+2235317.366254434**&f=json

--result:

```
{
 "geometries": [
  {
   "x": -120.59089279999577,
   "y": 35.107214200388704
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Jan 2020*: The previous formats shown threw the following error:

`OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'geometry_col.Long' in 'field list'")`

However, **this format worked:**

```
SELECT ST_X(geometry_col) AS longitude,
       ST_Y(geometry_col) AS latitude
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a library in .NET to be called from transact sql Converts WGS84/UTM coordinates to Latitude and Longitude

You can download it from github:

https://github.com/j-v-garcia/UTM2LATITUDE

usage:

SELECT dbo.UTM2LATITUDE(723399.51,4373328.5,'S',30) AS Latitude, dbo.UTM2LONGITUDE(723399.51,4373328.5,'S',30) AS Longitude

result:

```
39,4805657453054    -0,402592727245112

<param name="XUTM">pos UTM X</param>
<param name="YUTM">pos UTM Y</param>
<param name="LatBand">Latitude band grid zone designation letter (see http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm) </param>
<param name="LongBand">Longitude band grid zone designation number (see http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm) </param>
```